# Redirect from subdirectory of the document root to sibling directory (different subdirectory of the document root)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to internally redirect requests from `/media/myspecialdir/image.jpg` to `/myspecialdir/image.jpg`

If it was just an `.htaccess` file in the document root, this would be straight forward. The problem is that the `/media` directory already exists and contains contains an `.htaccess` file. This means that requests to `/media/myspecialdir/image.jpg` are intercepted by that `.htaccess` file.

Is it possible to redirect from a subdirectory of the document root to another subdirectory of the document root.

I've tried stuff like:

```
RewriteRule (.*) ../myspecialdir/$1 [L]
```

but this still prefixes a `media` dir to the rewritten URL.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Considering that your htaccess file is present inside media folder. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /media/

##Then your rules from here.........
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to redirect from a subdirectory of the document root to another subdirectory of the document root.

Yes that is definitely possible. Have this rule inside `/media/.htaccess`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .+ /myspecialdir/$1 [L]
```

This assumes that `myspecialdir` exists right under site root. Since you specifically asked for *internal rewrite*, this will keep URL as: `/media/myspecialdir/image.jpg` but will load content from `/myspecialdir/image.jpg`.